# How to avoid outdated xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some server side engine which generates xml files with client bill information.
On my web server I have some xsl file for transform this xml file in client's browser.

The header of xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "Windows-1251"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://my_test_server/bill.xsl"?>
```

From time to time I have to change the content of xsl file in order to change the representation of the bill for client. But browser cached xsl file and client see the old version of the bill.

Is there any way to say browser that xsl file in the cache is outdated and it has to load another one from server?

Comment: This is not an XML problem or an XSLT problem. This is a server configuration problem. You should search Stack Overflow or Server Fault for "Cache-Control" and the server you are using to figure out how to configure your server.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have full control over the web server and I'm afraid that I will spend a lot of time trying to convince server admins to change configuration.

Is there any other way to fix behavior of client browser? 

One way as I know is to change the name of the xsl. But it seem not good enough for me in some cases,

Comment: Probably you can add some query param to xsl url to prevent caching?

Comment: It doesn't help. After adding some extra params to URL xml file received from server, but xsl file from local cache.